# Chrome only works with Charles Proxy turned on, despite de-selecting all proxies

Tags: charles-proxy

I notice that my 2019 MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, I can only access the internet in Google Chrome and Safari with Charles Proxy turned on. I've attempted to follow the steps in https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/can-no-longer-browse-without-charles-running/ yet in System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies, Web Proxy (HTTP) and Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS) are already unchecked. What might be causing this behavior?

[image]